# Do I have to fully rebuild LLVM after editing a file?

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am tweaking LLVM files and do a "make" in my build director to rebuild LLVM with the tweaked files, which is taking a while even though my changes were rather small (I understand that my one file will be affect other files). Do I have to use 'cmake --build .' to generate a new make file in the build directory or is it right to just call 'make'. And is it common for rebuilds to take a while?

Comment: Are you building release or debug? If debug, it is worth looking at LLVM_OPTIMIZED_TABLEGEN. Building debug tablegen is very slow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, most time is spent re-linking the binaries, of which LLVM has many (`opt`, `llc`, etc.). One option to speed up the build is to enable `LLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB` and `LLVM_LINK_LLVM_DYLIB` and the other is to issue `make opt` instead of `make`, if you are mostly working with `opt`.

These options would make build system produce a single giant dynamic library (.so or .dll) containing all LLVM components (LLVMSupport, LLVMCodegen, etc), and make tools link to it. Linking to a dynamic library is much faster, because you don't need to re-link all the static code for each tool executable.

Comment: Thank you, could you elaborate how LLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB and LLVM_LINK_LLVM_DYLIB would help speed up?

Comment: @arthrax Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I'll rebuild it with those options

Answer (score 1):

Also if you for example just modify a backend target, then its enough to issue **make** in tools/llc dir. This way only the required tool will be relinked, thus fasten the build process.